# delete a row according to the information of the next one - R

Tags: r, row

I have a dataset called `mydata` that among other variables, contains these two like in the following extract:

```
plot.name    time.date
cam41        23
cam41        23
cam50        13
cam50        13
cam50        15
```

I'm trying to find a way to create an iterative control on each record with the following rules:

If the current row of `plot.name` is equal to the next one (e.g if `cam41 == cam41`) and the current row of `time.date` is equal to the next one (e.g if `23 == 23`), then delete the second row.

I was trying to do that with an `ifelse` but it doesn't work or maybe my code is just wrong.

Comment: You probably want to use `unique` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `unique` from base R or `distinct` from `dplyr`. The following should work if you need this condition applied to all columns in the data frame:

```
unique(df)

  plot.name time.date
1     cam41        23
3     cam50        13
5     cam50        15
```

Or:

```
dplyr::distinct(df)

  plot.name time.date
1     cam41        23
2     cam50        13
3     cam50        15
```

However, if you have multiple variables but are only concerned with `plot.name` and `time.date` consider the following with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  distinct(plot.name, time.date, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Or `duplicated` from base R:

```
df[!duplicated(df[c("plot.name", "time.date")]), ]
```

Comment: What if I have more variables in the dataset? How can I just consider these two variables? Something like 'mydata2 <- mydata[unique(mydata$plot.name) & unique(mydata$num.time),]' doesn't work...

Comment: `dplyr::distinct(df, plot.name, time.date, .keep_all = TRUE)` should do it.

Comment: Or `df[!duplicated(df[c("plot.name", "time.date")]),]` with base

Comment: happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose isn't to remove all duplicate rows with `unique` and you really want to check every rows by order :

```
df[head(df$plot.name, -1L) == df$plot.name[-1L] & head(df$time.date, -1L) == df$time.date[-1L], ]
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, (lead(plot.name) == plot.name & lead(time.date) == time.date) | row_number() == n())
```

Comment: I think you need to negate the condition inside `filter`

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I fix it with something like this:
`mydata2 <- mydata[!(mydata$plot.name == mydata$plot.name[-1L] & mydata$time.date == mydata$time.date[-1L]),]` even with warning message still works for me!